# OpenLdap replication

Tags: ldap, replication, openldap, master-slave, multi-master-replication

I'm working with openldap, every day i purge my ldap server and i import an ldif file. i have a master slave replication, so when i delete entries and import file, the slave delete all entries and update data and that was the problem, users can't access to server for a while.

I'm asking for a solution or an architecture that made my ldap server accessible and update the slave after importing file.

Answer (score 0):

When using replication you should not purge the complete database on the provider (master). The reason is that syncrepl makes use of operational attribute *entryUUID* which is generated each time an entry is added.

You should modify your update process to send modify requests to the running provider if data has to be changed. Depending on your replication config those changes will be immediately replicated.